# Postgres bitmask group by

Tags: postgresql, bit-manipulation, postgresql-9.2, bitmask

I have the following flags declared:

```
0 - None
1 - Read
2 - Write
4 - View
```

I want to write a query that will group on this bitmask and get the count of each flag used.

```
person  mask
  a      0
  b      3
  c      7
  d      6
```

The result should be:

```
flag        count
 none        1
 read        2
 write       3
 view        2
```

Any tips would be appreciated.

**For Craig**

```
SELECT  lea.mask as trackerStatusMask,
        count(*) as count
FROM    Live le 
INNER JOIN (
 ... --some guff
) lea on le.xId = lea.xId
WHERE   le.xId = p_xId   
GROUP BY lea.mask;
```

Comment: How're you using this mask in other queries? **What have you already tried**?

Comment: @CraigRinger, I have the group by so I can group on the mask and the count of that, I just have no idea how to split out the mask into the flags its comprised of.

Comment: OK, please show the partial query you already have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Simplest - pivoted result

Here's how I'd approach it:

```
 -- (after fixing the idiotic mistakes in the first version)
 SELECT
    count(nullif(mask <> 0, True)) AS "none",
    count(nullif(mask & 2,0))      AS "write",
    count(nullif(mask & 1,0))      AS "read",
    count(nullif(mask & 4,0))      AS "view"
FROM my_table;

-- ... though @ClodAldo's version of it below is considerably clearer, per comments.
```

This doesn't do a `GROUP BY` as such; instead it scans the table and collects the data in a single pass, producing column-oriented results.

If you need it in row form you can pivot the result, either using the `crosstab` function from the `tablefunc` module or by hand.

### If you really must `GROUP BY`, explode the bitmask

You cannot use `GROUP BY` for this in a simple way, because it expects rows to fall into exactly one group. Your rows appear in multiple groups. If you must use `GROUP BY` you will have to do so by generating an "exploded" bitmask where one input row gets copied to produce multiple output rows. This can be done with a `LATERAL` function invocation in 9.3, or with a SRF-in-SELECT in 9.2, or by simply doing a join on a `VALUES` clause:

```
SELECT
   CASE 
     WHEN mask_bit = 1 THEN 'read'
     WHEN mask_bit = 2 THEN 'write'
     WHEN mask_bit = 4 THEN 'view'
     WHEN mask_bit IS NULL THEN 'none'
   END AS "flag",
   count(person) AS "count"
FROM t
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    VALUES (4),(2),(1)
) mask_bits(mask_bit)
ON (mask & mask_bit = mask_bit)
GROUP BY mask_bit;
```

I don't think you'll have much luck making this as efficient as a single table scan, though.

Answer (score 3):

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/8bed0/2)

```
select
    count(mask = 0 or null) as "None",
    count(mask & 1 > 0 or null) as "Read",
    count(mask & 2 > 0 or null) as "Write",
    count(mask & 4 > 0 or null) as "View"
from t
```

Comment: I can't decide if I like your use of `or null` or not. It's standard, which is nice compared to `nullif`, but it's much less clear to read for people who aren't fluent in SQL.

Comment: @Craig And you know what? I'm fluent in SQL and whenever I see the `nullif` function I must make an effort to remember how does it work while the truth table is ready for consumption in my head, well..., not all days but at least in the good days :) My problem with `nullif` is so serious that I had to test your first query to be sure it is wrong, and I'm sorry to say it is.

Comment: It is? http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/8bed0/7 . Huh, it is too. Teach me not to test something, it contains two obvious and idiotic mistakes.

Comment: And one more seriously stupid mistake in the 'none' case... damn.